# C# - Create an animated GIF image from selected images in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, animated-gif

I need a solution to combine selected images into **1 animated GIF image**.

Im using Viual Studio 2010 and ASP.net 3.5 C#

Comment: I need a ruby encrusted Pony.

Comment: did you tried ***NGif***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [NGif](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ngif/) (A Component written using C#,it provide a way to create gif animations in .NET framework)

this code project article will help you - [NGif, Animated GIF Encoder for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11505/NGif-Animated-GIF-Encoder-for-NET)