# Converted Image to Gif, Works Partially?

Tags: c#, image-processing, animated-gif

I've written a short method for converting images(Image class) to a GifEncoder and finally saving that Gif to a file. However, when I go to open the resulting Gif created, it has some problems. 1) The Gif stops playing after 2 cycles in a browser. 2) When loaded through an image editor the colors seem to mix up a bit between pixels.

```
public void ConvertToGif( string DestinationPath , Image myImage , int myFrames ) {
    Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap( myImage.Width / myFrames , myImage.Height );
    GifBitmapEncoder myEncoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();

    int i = 0;
    while( i < myFrames ) {
        Graphics GrDrw = Graphics.FromImage( myBitmap );
        var DestRegion = new Rectangle( 0 , 0 , myBitmap.Width , myBitmap.Height );
        var SrceRegion = new Rectangle( myBitmap.Width * i , 0 , myBitmap.Width , myBitmap.Height );
        GrDrw.DrawImage( myImage , DestRegion , SrceRegion , GraphicsUnit.Pixel );
        BitmapSource mySource = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap( myBitmap.GetHbitmap() , IntPtr.Zero , Int32Rect.Empty , BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions() );
        myEncoder.Frames.Add( BitmapFrame.Create( mySource , mySource ) );
        GrDrw.Dispose();
        i += 1;
    }

    System.IO.FileStream myStream = new System.IO.FileStream( @DestinationPath , System.IO.FileMode.Create );
    myEncoder.Save( myStream );
}
```

The number of frames from an image created with ConvertToGif() also don't seem to register when running the resulting Gif through my other method, ConvertFromGif():

```
    public Image ConvertFromGif( Image myImage ) {
        var myDimensions = new FrameDimension( myImage.FrameDimensionsList[ 0 ] );
        var myFrames = myImage.GetFrameCount( myDimensions );
        var newImage = new Bitmap( myImage.Width * myFrames , myImage.Height );

        for( int i = 0; i < myFrames; i ++ ) {
            myImage.SelectActiveFrame( myDimensions , i );
            var DestRegion = new Rectangle( myImage.Width * i , 0 , myImage.Width , myImage.Height );
            var SrceRegion = new Rectangle( 0 , 0 , myImage.Width , myImage.Height );

            Graphics GrDrw = Graphics.FromImage( newImage );
            GrDrw.DrawImage( myImage , DestRegion , SrceRegion , GraphicsUnit.Pixel );
            GrDrw.Dispose();
        }

        return newImage;
    }
```

I can run any Gif through my ConvertFromGif() method, but Gifs made by my ConvertToGif() method won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a Look around and discovered that GifBitmapEncoder is only really meant to read GIFs so they can be displayed in WPF this class will allow you to create multi-framed GIFs however it does not provide a Metadata handler that allows you to put key frame information like cycle count, delay between frame etc. They have left the Metadata part out for 3rd parties to implement

> Unfortunately we don't expose a metadata reader or writer for GIFs
>   (animated or otherwise). In order to produce correct animated GIFs,
>   you need to write out some metadata with timing information. Since we
>   don't provide a GIF metadata handler, we do provide a mechanism for
>   3rd parties to write their own. Documentation for writing a metadata
>   handler can be found here:
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737407.aspx as well as in
>   this article
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dnlong/html/wiccodec.asp.

Quote from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ef358a7-d1ac-4267-91d9-166024aad8ca/creating-animated-gif-files-in-wpf?forum=wpf

Gifs have some default timing information so you are getting the 2 cycles but that is all it may also differ from other browsers etc.

Also while looking online I saw other users having the same issue with colour bleed between frames.

There is two avenues for you: Use a 3rd party .Net Library that allows you to write Gifs or write you own.

From your previous question [Convert a List of Images to a GIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007046/convert-a-list-of-images-to-a-gif/23007578?noredirect=1#comment35281758_23007578) I would suggest you use NGif - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11505/NGif-Animated-GIF-Encoder-for-NET

However if you want to create your own metadata writer for the GifBitmapEncoder follow the links provided on the post above for the documentation for metadata read and writers.